# How to check website cpu usage programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, iis, cpu

Does anyone know how to check the CPU usage of a website in IIS or by any other means? Thanks very much.

Comment: Programmatically, or does this belong on superuser or serverfault?

Comment: It belongs here as long as you mean programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to calculate the CPU Usage Programmatically using C# or VB.NET](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/10/how-to-calculate-cpu-usage.html) using [PerformanceCounter.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx)

```
static PerformanceCounter cpuUsage;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

    Console.WriteLine(cpuUsage.NextValue() + " %");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(cpuUsage.NextValue() + " %");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the CPU performance counter is one way.